# Pass an object from a webapi method to another webapi method which is in different solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two web api project in different solutions.for eg. Soln1.Project1 and Soln2.Project2
Client invokes a post method on api/controller/action in Project1 passing a message body of an object say CustomerA
From Project1->api/controller/action i need to invoke a api method in Project2 passing the CustomerA object but CustomerA is not available in Project2.
Project2 has got similar object called CustomerB. Could anyone please recommend a best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here

1. Create shared `YourObjectLib.dll` that will contain simple POCO objects with none or minimum logic.
   Include that library in both projects by shared file system or by nuget package.
2. Use `dynamic` objects. When recipient does not have a class you are trying to deserialize (`CustomerA` in your case) - it just creates `dynamic` object.